# How to check if span od xheckbox is checked in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have html form, javascript ajax code and php code that sends email.

I have one problem.

My checkboxes are made with span (see code). How to check if this span with class checkmark are checked.

My html:

```
<form id="obrazec" class="form-inline">     
    <input  class="okno" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>

    <input type="checkbox" id="trgovina" value="" name="trgovina">Spletna trgovina <span class="checkmark"></span>

    <input type="checkbox" id="oglasevanje" value="" name="oglasevanje">Oglaševanje <span class="checkmark"></span>

    <input type="checkbox" id="trgovina" value="" name="strani">Spletna stran <span class="checkmark"></span>

    <div class="submitdiv">
        <button class="submit" id="potrdi" type="button" onclick>POŠLJI</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button#potrdi").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        var formData = $('#my_form').serialize();


        var email = $("#email").val();






        var boolMAIL = email.includes("@");
        var dataString = 'email=' + email;




        if(boolMAIL == true ){
        $.ajax({
            url:"action_page.php", 
            type: "POST",
            data: dataString, 
            success:function(result){

               $( ".response" ).show();
                              $( ".response2" ).hide();

               $( "#obrazec" ).hide();
            $( ".prijavatext" ).hide();

            }

        });
        }
        else
        {
               $( ".response2" ).show();


        }
    });


});


</script>
```

My php:

```
 $email = $_POST['email'];


    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];

    $email_from = 'test@test.si';
    $email_subject = "Novo povprasevanje";
    $email_body = "Novo povprasevanje: 
   $email.\n ".




    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";                      
    $to = "test@test.com";
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);


    ?>
```

It works ok (email) and i get mail but i don't know how to check if checkbox is checked because it is not check box actually but field:

```
<span class="checkmark"></span>
```

Comment: Your checkboxes have `name`s and `id`s.

Comment: Well if i add:     $trgovina = isset($_POST['trgovina']) ? 1 : 0;
to php and

Comment: var trgovina = $("#trgovina").val();
 and .... + '&trgovina=' + trgovina; to javacript i allways get 1

Comment: Do not write code in comments. __Update__ your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of a specific property using Jquery you need to utilize the **.prop()** method.
Since you want to know if a checkbox is checked or not the related property is **checked**.

```
var trgovina = $("#trgovina").prop("checked");
console.log(trgovina);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already use `jquery` you can get all fields from form (**except** buttons/type=submit) with `serialize()` method (and you already have this method in your code). Your javascript will look like:

```
$("button#potrdi").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var boolMAIL = email.includes("@");

    if(boolMAIL == true ){
        $.ajax({
            url:"action_page.php", 
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#obrazec').serialize(), 
            success:function(result){

               $( ".response" ).show();
               $( ".response2" ).hide();

               $( "#obrazec" ).hide();
            $( ".prijavatext" ).hide();

            }
        });
    }
```

On server side your **checked** checkboxes will be available via their `name` attributes, `$_POST['trgovina']` for example. And **not checked** checkboxes will not be in POST array.